# Asp.net radiobutton value not entered in Access db

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string menu = "";
        if (RadioButton3.Checked)
            menu = menu + " " + RadioButton3.Text;
        if (RadioButton4.Checked)
            menu = menu + " " + RadioButton4.Text;
        if (RadioButton5.Checked)
            menu = menu + " " + RadioButton5.Text;
        if (RadioButton6.Checked)
            menu = menu + " " + RadioButton6.Text;
        TextBox4.Text = menu;
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into bill(name,contact,address,order) values(@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4)", con);
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a1", RadioButton1.Text+TextBox1.Text);
        else  if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a1", RadioButton2.Text+TextBox1.Text);
        else cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a1", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a2", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a3", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a4", TextBox4.Text );
con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

This is my code, the fourth  parameter value is not getting add to my database. Also note that there is no restrictions placed in the db column (order)

Comment: Shows me a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should thrown an exception. A `Syntax Error` exception caused by the word **ORDER**. This is a reserved keyword for Access (and probably for every other database on earth).

If you don't see the exception then there is a try catch handler that doesn't show the error message around this code.

In any case you could fix the problem enclosing the problematic word with square brackets as

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into bill
                    (name,contact,address,[order]) 
                     values(@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4)", con);
```

and remember to remove the empty try catch or at least add a meaningful message.

Comment: I suggest to change that column name (If you still able to do so). Otherwise this problem will resurface everytime you need to use that column.